# Windows cmd/batch copy specific file names

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to copy specific file names from multiple folders to one folder.
Say i want to copy everything containing 2017 in its name.

When i want to copy everything the following seems to be working:

```
for /r %i in (*) do copy "%i" "c:\users\alexander\desktop\test"
```

Only zip files:

```
for /r %i in (*.zip) do copy "%i" "c:\users\alexander\desktop\test"
```

Although this does not seem to work for name variables like:

```
for /r %i in (*"2017") do copy "%i" "c:\users\alexander\desktop\test"
```

How can i filter on all files containing 2017?

Comment: How about `for /r %i in ("*2017*") do copy "%~i" "c:\users\alexander\desktop\test"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
for /R %i in (*2017*) do copy "%i" "c:\users\alexander\desktop\test"
```

Comment: Great, ill try it as soon as i'm home!
Thanks!

Comment: Works perfect Gerard! Thanks!